# Select different visualforce pages from a multi-select picklist

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-template, getcontentaspdf

I'm working on a custom button to print PDF invoice with different templates. When a user click on Print Invoice button on record page, a screen with multi-select picklist will pop up and let user choose the template they want to print.

I'm using VF to store the template, but still haven't know the solution to select different template from a multi-select picklist. Is there any way to call VF pages from a multi-select picklist field?

My 1st solution right now is create a screen flow -> have a multi-select picklist field -> each field is a Visualforce url (refer to [this document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_internal_vf_finish.htm&type=5), but right now it cannot get the VF pages).

Is there any other possible solution to select different visualforce pages from a multi-select picklist?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.